# AngularJS service that sets property over REST fails to correctly set

Tags: javascript, rest, angularjs

Given the following AngularJS:

```
var app = angular.module('testing',[]);
app.service('auth',function($http)  
{  
    var user = '';  
    $http.get("http://localhost/auth/user").success(function(data)  
    {  
        user = data.user;    
        console.log("User: " + user); //prints Woot4Moo
    });
    return{  
         getUser: function(){    
              return user;  
         }  
     };
});
```

JSON response:

```
{"user":"Woot4Moo"}
```

usage in controller:

```
app.controller('controller',function($http,auth)  
{  
          $http({  
                url:"http://localhost/my/rest/call/",  
                method: "GET",  
                params: {person: auth.getUser()}   //this comes back empty
          }).success(function(data){...}  
};
```

So to reiterate how do I get my end url to be this:

```
http://localhost/my/rest/call/?user='Woot4Moo'
```

instead of invalid like this:

```
http://localhost/my/rest/call/?user=     <- the empty string
```

Answer (score 1):

You're making an async, HTTP call in `auth`.

When the app first starts, the controller requests the value of `user` immediately from your service and gets the set empty string. Only when the success callback, which is triggered later, is called is the value set for `user`.

You can do this:

```
app.service('auth',function($http)  
{  
    var user; 
    function queryUser() {
      return $http.get("http://localhost/auth/user").then(function(data)  
      {  
          user = data.data.user;
          return user;
      });
    }

    function getUser() {
      return user ? user : queryUser();
    }

    return{  
         getUser: getUser
     };
});
```

Ensuring that on the initial request for a user, `queryUser` is called, then once the value is cached into `user`, all subsequent calls will return the cached value.

Call the function `getUser()` internally in the service to set the value at initialization if you need to.

I would also look into changing the logic in your controller. Depending on an async call immediately like that is probably not a good idea!

Example [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5BZlOG?p=preview)

Comment: While this works with Angular's view system, it's important to realize that `getUser` will return *either* a string **or** a promise, depending on if the data is cached or not--in many cases, it may be necessary or prudent to make the public API more consistent in order to avoid weird race condition bugs (e.g. cache the promise and return it every time).

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you just want to change the end url,

```
$location.url("my/rest/call/?user='"+user+"'");
```

should work.

Hope this helped